# 404 after changing routes in ASP NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I had working routes on my app that looked like this:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Category",
            url: "{name}-c{categoryId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", name = "ErrorName" },
            namespaces: new[] { "B2B.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "InfoPage",
            url: "{name}-i{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "InfoPages", action = "Details", name = "ErrorName" },
            namespaces: new[] { "B2B.Controllers" });
```

I've changed the dash (-) to the hash (#) because spaces are changed in url to dashes.

```
 url: "{name}#c{categoryId}",
 url: "{name}#i{id}",
```

Now I've this same routes with only this one char changed and I get 404 on urls like this:

```
siteadess:1234/1.0.1-Podstawowa%23c4
```

I've also tried to change hash to under score and it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use hashes(#) in a URL route because anything after the hash is never sent to the server.

So your route `/{name}#c{categoryId}` will never get hit because the closest that the server will ever see is `/{name}`

Comment: Thanks. But what about underscore? Is it forbidden also? Im looking for some safe character which wouldn't be used by users in {name}.

Comment: Underscores should be fine.

Comment: @Paulie What is your url template when using underscores?

Comment: @ChaoticLoki I've found out that I cant use any dots (.) in url. It was the reason that adress with underscore didn't worked. Also hashtag is ok too! It was the dots all the time :)

Comment: You might want to be careful with using hashtags, the only reason why its working is probably because you are encoding it to %23, if you do really use the # character, you will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of routing didn't worked were dots in the url adress.

```
siteadess:1234/1.0.1-Podstawowa%23c4
```

After removing dots everything works perfect!
As sugested by others I've also replaced hashtag with underscore.